# How to debug an error of "'module' object is not callable"?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import json
import pybase64
import datetime
import requests

//CAPTURING A PICTURE AND SAVING IT//
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(0.5)
camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/rasppi/images/image2.jpg")
camera.stop_preview()

//CONVERTING INTO BASE64 STRING//
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/rasppi/images/image2.jpg", "rb") as file:
    string = pybase64.b64encode(file.read())
    file.close()

url = "192.168.139.87:9000/upload"

payload = string
//USING POST REQUEST TO UPLOAD IMAGE ON URL//
response = requests('post', url, data = payload)
now  = datetime.datetime.now()
time = str(now)
obj = json.loads(response.text)
id = ["emp_id"]
var = "Identified person is : " + id
print(var)
print(time)


It generates following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "get_image.py", line 22, in <module>
   response = requests('post', url, data = payload)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This code deals with the program for capturing a picture with the help of raspberry pi and then POST it on the url. The POST request command shows some error.

Comment: But indeed `requests` is a module and not a callable. Perhaps you wanted to access some function defined in (attribute of) `requests`?

Comment: requests.post(url, data=payload)

Comment: i tried requests.post(url, data=payload), it shows the same error

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: when i used the above solution, it gave following error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_image.py", line 22, in <module>
    response = requests.post( url, data = payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  ("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '192.168.139.87:9000/upload'